# Recolouring a transparent png and layering it onto another png on the fly

Tags: php, png, transparent

I've been struggling with getting what is possibly a quite simple bit of code working and as a last resort, I'm reaching out for help!

The basic goal is to layer 2 pngs and output them to the browser without saving them to disk.  The difficulty comes as I want to recolour the layered image on the fly to the users preference.  From all of the posts on here (thanks guys) and other sites, I've managed to get it working to a level, however not without saving the image.

Here is the background image (in this case a t-shirt)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgKLd.png)

and here is the layer (a transparent 1, coloured black)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtuJJ.png)

Comment: Please post the code here

Comment: It wont let me post a message larger than 600 characters - presumably because I'm new to Stack Overflow?

Comment: Then post it on a code sharing service and put the link here